# Error starting node.js localserver - undefined EventEmitter prototype

Tags: javascript, ubuntu-14.04, node.js, chromebook, chroot

I'm trying to use [Coder](http://googlecreativelab.github.io/coder/). Coder is an application developed by google based on node.js server. It was initially designed for the Raspberry Pi, but according to the Coder project in GitHub, it should work also on other plaftorms, including on a [Chromebook with crouton](https://github.com/googlecreativelab/coder/wiki/Coder-on-a-Chromebook-with-Crouton)
I followed the steps described in the former link and installed node.js v7.2.1 on a crouton chroot (trusty 14.04). But when I try to start the local server with

```
$ node localserver.js
```

I get the following error:

```
/home/rodrigo/tmp/coder/coder-base/node_modules/socket.io/lib/store.js:35
 Store.prototype.__proto__ = EventEmitter.prototype;
                                ^                                         
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/rodrigo/tmp/coder/coder-base/node_modules/socket.io/lib/store.js:35:41)
at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/rodrigo/tmp/coder/coder-base/node_modules/socket.io/lib/manager.js:16:13)
at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
```

I'm using the original Coder files in GitHub, no modifications were done. Do you know how could I fix that error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

process.EventEmitter was deprecated and not working in new node version

https://github.com/LearnBoost/websocket.io/issues/55